# How to Sort User list by meta_key and meta_value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very newbie in wordpress and stuck into a task for many hours and not getting any way to sort out this, Thats why I am here....

I want to display a sort list of user based on meta key and meta value but I dont Know what wrong with me I searched google and did as retrieve...

I am trying as:

```
<?php
$args  = array(  
  'fields' => 'all_with_meta',  
  'meta_query' => array(  
    array(  
    'key' => 'status', // the meta field (or key) we want to target  
    'value' => '1'  // the value we want to target (optional)  

    )  
));  

$users = get_users($args);  
foreach ($users as $client) {
        echo '<li>' . $client->user_email . '</li>';
    }
?>
```

and in wp meta user table:
**meta_key**=>'status'
and
**meta_value**=>'1'   for three rows but it showing constant result for any value of meta_value.

Please let me know why I am not getting my desire output... thank you

Comment: which database table do 'status' and '1' exist?

Comment: wp_usermeta table contain 'status' and '1'

Comment: the above code is correct. I tested it with my wp_usermeta table. the output varies with status and key values. or if you have any specific problem you need to show the rows you have in the table which are giving you the same output.